# Round values to one decimal place in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to change the decimal value to one digit in javascript.For eg. I have value 5 and I need to show 5.0 in my javascript function .

Answer (score 5):

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Ltn/)</kbd>

Use **`toFixed()`** Javascript function

#### JavaScript

```
var num = 5;
var n = num.toFixed(1);
console.log(n);
```

#### Console Output

```
5.0
```

**`toFixed()`** Function [**`References`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

---

#### *Updated Answer*

Above answer return string but OP's require float value, use **`parseFloat()`** function,

#### Javascript

```
var num = 5;
var n = parseFloat(num).toFixed(1);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: It works for me.But I need it as a decimal not as string.

Comment: oky i update my answet use parseFloat() function

Answer (score 2):

**[Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)**

> Returns
>
> A string representation of number that does not use exponential
>   notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The
>   number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with
>   zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If number is
>   greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls
>   Number.prototype.toString() and returns a string in exponential
>   notation.

**Examples**

```
var numObj = 12345.6789; 
numObj.toFixed();         // Returns "12346": note rounding, no fractional part  
numObj.toFixed(1);        // Returns "12345.7": note rounding  
numObj.toFixed(6);        // Returns "12345.678900": note added zeros
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);    // Returns "123000000000000000000.00"
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);    // Returns "0.00"
2.34.toFixed(1);          // Returns "2.3"
-2.34.toFixed(1);         // Returns -2.3 (due to operator precedence, negative number literals don't return a string...)
(-2.34).toFixed(1);       // Returns "-2.3" (...unless you use parentheses)
```